# Can I put a for loop inside scanf?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, scanf

I want to have unknown amount of inputs in a single line. For example, user can input:
"ans: 1 2 3 4 5"
and scanf() will store these five numbers to an array. The problem is that the program don't know how many input will there be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int input[4];
    scanf("ans: " for(i = 0, i < 3,i++){scanf(" %d", &input[i]);};
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry I'am totally new to coding, what will be the proper way to write this? Or is this impossible?
Thanks :)

Comment: You can't. And for such a small number of values, why not just use `scanf("ans: %d %d %d %d", &input[0], &input[1], &input[2], &input[3])`? For larger amount of values, read `"ans: "` separately (if you really want the user to enter that) and then use a separate loop for the numeric input. And don't forget to check what `scanf` *returns*!

Comment: You put scanf inside the loop, not the other way around. You are kind of asking how to put the race track inside your car, rather than how to put your car on the race track. If you don't know how many inputs there will be in advance, a while loop is usually preferred.

Comment: What would determine the actual number of inputs? The size of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` with `"%n"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char input[100];
    int arr[10];

    //fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
    strcpy(input, "1 2 42 56 -3 0 2018\n"); // fgets

    char *pi = input;
    int tmp, pp, i = 0;
    while (sscanf(pi, "%d%n", &tmp, &pp) == 1) {
        if (i == 10) { fprintf(stderr, "array too small\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
        pi += pp;
        arr[i++] = tmp;
    }
    printf("got this ==>");
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) printf(" %d", arr[k]);
    puts("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked this question way round.

You can achieve what you expect by putting scanf inside of a loop.Even you can ask user to give how many inputs he want to enter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int input[4];
    printf("Enter the number of inputs you want to give : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n;i++)
    {
     printf("Enter the input number %d : ",i);
     scanf("%d", &input[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```